# NFC ACR122U-A9 connecting error with delphi

Tags: delphi, unicode, nfc, delphi-xe8, acr122

I just bought a NFC ACR122U.
It comes with samples to delphi 7.

I am using delphi XE8 and compiling the sample to 32 bits/win 8.1.

I did the correct changes(I believe) to adapt the api and sample project functions to delphi Xe8, replacing Pchar to PAnsiChar and Char to AnsiChar where needed.

I am using native win 8 drivers, no manufacturer drive.

I can initialize the device and get the device name correctly with:

```
procedure TfrmDevProg.btnInitClick(Sender: TObject);
var index: integer;
begin

  //Establish context
  retCode := SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER,
                                   nil,
                                   nil,
                                   @hContext);
  if retCode <> SCARD_S_SUCCESS then begin
    displayout(GetScardErrMsg(retcode),2);
    Exit;
  end ;

  //List PC/SC readers installed in the system
  BufferLen := MAX_BUFFER_LEN;
  retCode := SCardListReadersA(hContext,
                               nil,
                               @Buffer,
                               @BufferLen);
  if retCode <> SCARD_S_SUCCESS then begin
    DisplayOut(getscarderrmsg(retCode),2);
    Exit;
  end;

  btnInit.Enabled := false;
  btnConnect.Enabled := true;

  LoadListToControl(cbReader,@buffer,bufferLen);
  // Look for ACR128 PICC and make it the default reader in the combobox
  for index := 0 to cbReader.Items.Count-1 do begin
    cbReader.ItemIndex := index;
    if AnsiPos('ACR122U PICC', cbReader.Text) > 0 then
      Exit;
  end;
  cbReader.ItemIndex := 0;

end;
```

The procedure above works very well. Next, I use the next code to connect to device:

```
procedure TfrmDevProg.btnConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  //Connect to reader using a shared connection
  retCode := SCardConnectA(hContext,
                           PAnsiChar(cbReader.Text),
                           SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
                           SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 or SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1,
                           @hCard,
                           @dwActProtocol);

  if retcode <> SCARD_S_SUCCESS then begin
    displayout(GetScardErrMsg(retcode),2)
  end
  else begin
    displayout('Successful connection to ' + cbReader.Text, 1)
  end;
end;
```

Here, I am getting an error from SCardConnectA: "The specified reader name is not recognized." and the retcode var is: -2146435063.

Here is a snippet code of the api copied from DVD sent with the device, when I bought it:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Imported functions from Winscard.dll (WIN32 API)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Function SCardEstablishContext(dwscope :DWORD;
                                pvReserved1: LPCVOID;
                                pvReserved2: LPCVOID;
                                phContext :LPSCARDCONTEXT):LONG; stdcall; external 'Winscard.dll';

Function SCardReleaseContext(hContext:SCARDCONTEXT):LONG; stdcall; external 'Winscard.dll';

Function SCardListReadersA(hContext : SCARDCONTEXT;
                           mszGroups:LPCSTR;
                           szReaders:LPSTR;
                           pcchReaders:LPDWORD):LONG; stdcall; external 'Winscard.dll';

//Note : ScardConnectA is for non-UNICODE characters which is only one byte.
//       For UNICODE characters it is SCardConnectW. Special processing is
//       required for UNICODE. Be careful!
Function SCardConnectA(hContext : SCARDCONTEXT;
                       szReaders:LPSTR;
                       dwShareMode : DWORD;
                       dwPreferredProtocols : DWORD;
                       phCard : LPSCARDHANDLE;
                       pdwActiveProtocols:LPDWORD):LONG; stdcall; external 'Winscard.dll';
```

I downloaded an binary app from mannufacturer site  to test the device and all works well. But I need do it work with my Delphi app.

Any help, please.

Comment: try these:`retCode := SCardConnectA(hContext,
                           PAnsiChar(AnsiString(cbReader.Text)),
                           SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
                           SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 or SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1,
                           @hCard,
                           @dwActProtocol);`

Comment: It works very well. Very thanks.

Comment: @Fritzw, can you expand that into an answer?

Comment: As side note: now ACR122U is obsolete coupler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the cast from cbReader.Text do PAnsiChar.
fix it to

```
retCode := SCardConnectA(hContext, PAnsiChar(AnsiString(cbReader.Text)), SCARD_SHARE_SHARED, SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 or SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, @hCard, @dwActProtocol);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Fritz